# "Tous" in subject-verb-"tous" means what?

Tags: grammaire, prononciation, pronoms

How do you say, “We know everything,” versus, “We all know”? My first impulse with either is to say the same thing:

> Nous savons tous.

Also, do you pronounce the *s* in *tous* in either case?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Nous savons tous* means *"We all know"* and you pronounce the final "s".

*Nous savons tout* means *"We know everything"* and you do not pronounce the final "t".

Comment: Notice also that “Nous le savons tous” is more likely than “Nous savons tous”.

Comment: yes, as @Stephane says, "Nous savons tous" is usually followed by "que ...", otherwise we write “Nous le savons tous” ("we all know it")